# DS4 controller driver en Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, server, driver, ps4

I am currently trying to install DS4 driver on a Windows Server 2019, I have tried multiple things :

- Try using DS4Windows
- Try install Steam and configure the controller using Big Picture, but no controller was found, probably because it needs to be recognized by Windows first
- Try extract driver from my PC on Win10 but not possible as they are Windows drivers and cannot be exported

I managed to make the x360 controller work on my Windows Server by exporting drivers from my win10 PC, but it is not possible for DS4 controller.

On my Win10 the controller is automatically recognized and the drivers are installed automatically too, so I guess the DS4 controller support is removed from Windows Server...

I anybody manage to install these drivers, or have any idea it would be great, I am currently out of any idea, so any help would be awesome!